# Find available time slots for table reservation system

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, join

I am creating a database for table reservation system. Each table have it's own time slot list and I want to find **available** time slots for each table.
So I have the following tables:

```
time_slots table
----------------------------------
id || table_id || weekday ||  time
==================================
 1           1          1    12:00
 2           1          1    12:30
...
11           1          1    16:00
...
17           1          1    19:00
18           1          1    19:30
...
27           1          1    00:00
==================================

reservations table
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id || table_slot_id ||          start_date ||            end_date
=================================================================
 1                1    2020-06-01 12:00:00    2020-06-01 12:20:00
 2                1    2020-06-01 16:00:00    2020-06-01 19:00:00
=================================================================
```

I wrote query which allows to find all **reserved** time slots:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_slots, (SELECT * 
                   FROM reservations 
                   WHERE reservations.start_date::date = '2020-06-01'::date) as res
WHERE table_slots.weekday = extract(dow from '2020-06-01'::date)
AND table_slots.time BETWEEN res.start_date::time and res.end_date::time
ORDER BY table_slots.time
```

But I don't understand how to write query to find available time slots. So I expect that result should contain all time_slots where time is between 12:30 and 15:30; 19:30 and 00:00. How to do this?
Is it possible to write such queries with minimal overhead?
And the last question, is this good design for such systems? If not then what is the better designs in these scenerios.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `not exists`. This would give you all available slots on June 1st:

```
select ts.*
from time_slots ts
where not exists (
    select 1
    from reservations r
    where 
        r.table_slot_id = ts.id
        and r.start_date >= '2020-06-01'::date
        and r.start_date <  '2020-07-01'::date
        and r.start_date::time <= ts.time
        and r.end_date::time   >  ts.time 
)
```

Note that this assumes that reservations do not span across days.

It might be more efficient to express the `where` clause of the subquery as:

```
    where 
        r.table_slot_id = ts.id
        and r.start_date >= '2020-06-01'::date
        and r.start_date <= '2020-06-01'::date + ts.time::interval
        and r.end_date   >  '2020-06-01'::date + ts.time::interval
```

This would take advantage of an index on `reservations(table_slot_id, start_date, end_date)`.

Comment: But the query result includes all time slots except 12:00